# pytesser IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: ioerror

I´m trying to use pytesser but I´m getting this error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

I´m using a mac machine and the code I´m using is this:

```
from pytesser import *
import os

im = Image.open('/screenshot.png')
text = image_to_string(im)
print text
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your directory structure?  Does ```/screenshot.png``` actually exist?  I don't think that is the file path you are assuming it is.  Maybe try ```./screenshot.png```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I manage to solve the problem. First I installed Homebrew, and then tesseract. Afterwards the problem was solved.